# How can I trigger a click event on a Component using the Robot class?

Tags: java, swing, event-handling, mouseevent, awtrobot

I need to trigger a MouseEvent mouseClicked on a JLabel (or any other component for that matter). How do I do this?

I tried it using the Robot class as follows:

```
try {
    Robot r=new Robot();
    r.mouseMove(jl.gettX(), jl.getY());//jl is the JLabel
    r.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
    r.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
} catch (AWTException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

but the `getX()` and `getY()` are returning the `x,y` positions of the component's parent. How do I get the absolute position of a component so that I can trigger `Robot.mousePress()`? Is there any other way to trigger the event on a specific component?

Comment: why is the negative vote?? i wonder??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [Component.getLocationOnScreen()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#getLocationOnScreen%28%29) instead. This method returns absolute coordinates.

Comment: I wondered the same thing.  `gLOS` is the correct one to use in order to get 'location on screen'.  @mKorbel if you should notice, why the edit?

Comment: hmmm I'm going througt OP's JLabel, then why casting JLabel to the Component, but agreed :-)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using [FEST-Swing](http://code.google.com/p/fest/) which allows you to write code that looks like this `dialog.button("ok").click();`

It is normally used for testing [Swing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swing_%28Java%29) components, but actually you can use it at other times too. You may find it useful to set the name of the component so you can find them easily with fest.